# Dynamic Attribute Names in Shopify Cart

Tags: dynamic, attributes, shopify

I'm so close on this, but I just can't get the syntax right.  I've been messing with this off and on for days.  Essentially I have a greeting card message and I want the message to be filled in by the customer for every Greeting Card on the checkout page (cart.liquid) and I need the attribute name to change for every index.  Therefore I'm adding the index to each attribute name, but to no avail.   For testing purposes, here's a basic input field:

```
    <p class="cart-attribute__field" style="min-width:300px;">
      <label for="to{{ forloop.index }}">To:</label>
      <input class="checkMe" id="to{{ forloop.index  }}" type="text" name="attributes[To{{ forloop.index  }}]"  maxlength="40" data-stk="{{item.id}}" value="{{ cart.attributes['To'+forloop.index] }}" >

    </p>
```

And its this part (value="{{ cart.attributes['To'+forloop.index] }}") that is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use '+' operator in liquid code to append. Try this instead:

```
{% assign cart_attr = 'To' | append: forloop.index %}
<p class="cart-attribute__field" style="min-width:300px;">
<label for="to{{ forloop.index }}">To:</label>
<input class="checkMe" id="to{{ forloop.index  }}" type="text" name="attributes[To{{ forloop.index  }}]"  maxlength="40" data-stk="{{item.id}}" value="{{ cart.attributes[cart_attr] }}" >
</p>
```

*Note: Improvise as required.*

Comment: Yep a shopify expert got back to me and this was the answer.  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: By chance do you know how to clear the attribute properties?  Appears to keep the information in the admin section even if an item is removed from the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not just use line item properties as described on https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/product-page/get-customization-information-for-products

Comment: Line items are not editable in the checkout page for the customer as with my store this is a must (greeting card messages).  It was causing my customers a headache having to remove an item, then readd.  Therefore cart attributes were my saving grace.

Comment: Didn't mean on the checkout but rather on the actual product page where they add the gift card to the cart in the first place.

Comment: Yep I knew what you meant.  I'm on the same page.